# помогите составить regexp выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Предположим имеется следующй текст:

```
Testing for bugs, this is test
ABC: test bug - testing bugs
123: we are testing application, this is our test case -bug
```

Текст может повторяться на странице в разном виде много раз и мне нужно написать регулярное выражение которое бы находило только слова **test** и **bug** в строке которая начинается на ABC

я пытался использовать что-то такое: `(?<=ABC)(test)|(bug)`
но почему-то в результате выбираются не только слова во второй строке, но так же и в первой и третьей

К сожалению я совсем не опытен в вопросах регулярных выражений и у меня не получилось разобраться самостоятельно.

Подскажите пожалуйста как ограничить поиск только второй строкой, начинающейся на ABC?

https://regexr.com/6iav3

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `/\b(?<=^ABC.*)(?:test|bug)\b/gm`- https://regexr.com/6ib6j

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew человеку вроде пхп нужен, а там нельзя `.*` впихать в просмотры

Comment: Если пройти по ссылке на тест регулярного выражения, то там установлена опция *JavaScript*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Спасибо
А если изменить вопрос таким образом что бы слова test и bug искались между 'ABC:' и '123:'
то как должен выглядеть regex?

Comment: `/\b(?<=ABC:.*)(?:test|bug)\b(?=.*123:)/g`